# Whether Minio Object Storage server can be ported/run on embedded Linux platform?

Tags: embedded-linux, object-storage, minio

There is a requirement to have an Object Storage server (preferably open source) to be run on Embedded Linux platform. We are thinking to use Minio as Object Storage server. The question is whether Minio Object Storage server can be ported/run on embedded Linux platform like Xilinx based Linux system?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it's a good idea to run product like `Minio` on embedded hardware. Various CPU- and RAM-intensive optimization techniques (e. g. compression, deduplication, erasure coding, journaling) are likely to be used in this kind of software. Are you sure your embedded system is powerfull enough to make this job? Also (in most cases) you'll have to pay attention to the fault tolerance and high availability, which means that you will need to run `Minio` cluster on independent devices interacting via network.

So I think it's problem of architecture of your product rather then compilation.

Comment: Yes, I agree with you. We are also not in favour of running Minio or any kind of Object Storage on embedded platform. We are just evaluating various options. Thank you so much.